# I want to use Gatsby.js to get RSS data from GraphQL. GraphiQL or I am able to get it successfully

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I want to use Gatsby.js to get RSS data from GraphQL.
GraphiQL or I am able to get it successfully.
I have attached a picture of the error.
It is showing up in the browser.

I have also attached an image of GraphiQL.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqc0S.png)

```
import React from "react"
import HeaderFeedCell from "./HeaderFeedCell";
import * as styles from"./HeaderRssFeedList.module.css"
import { graphql,useStaticQuery} from "gatsby";

const HeaderRssFeedList = () => {
  const {data} = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
    query {
      allFeedAlfalfa {
        nodes {
            title
            pubDate
            link
            content
            id
        }
        }
    }
    ` )
  return (
  
    <ul>
  {data.allFeedAlfalfa.node.map(feed => {
                    return <li><HeaderFeedCell feed={feed} /></li>
                })}
    </ul>
  )


}
export default HeaderRssFeedList;
```

error image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT84X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node is the `{allFeedAlfalfa}` or `data.allFeedAlfalfa`, not `data` destructured as `{data}`. Use:

```
import React from "react"
import HeaderFeedCell from "./HeaderFeedCell";
import * as styles from"./HeaderRssFeedList.module.css"
import { graphql,useStaticQuery} from "gatsby";

const HeaderRssFeedList = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
    query {
      allFeedAlfalfa {
        nodes {
            title
            pubDate
            link
            content
            id
        }
        }
    }
    ` )
  return (
  
    <ul>
  {data.allFeedAlfalfa.node.map(feed => {
                    return <li><HeaderFeedCell feed={feed} /></li>
                })}
    </ul>
  )


}
export default HeaderRssFeedList;
```

The `useStaticQuery` returns a `data` object with your node inside, so you need to destructure the property itself, not `data`.

You can destructurate the node as `{allFeedAlfalfa}` if you wish.

Comment: This problem was resolved thanks to your support